# C fopen() error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘FILE’ from type ‘struct FILE *’

Tags: c, struct, char, fopen

I am currently in process of making an image-processing program and it is going pretty well but suddenly some `fopen()` errors appeared. In my previous version (no dynamically allocated arrays, no structs) it was okay, `char name[50]` was used in `fopen(name, "a")` and it worked good but now I cannot make it work at all. Whatever I throw in `fopen()`, it does not compile. Here is full error description:

> obsluga.c:30:8: error: incompatible types when assigning to type
>   ‘FILE’ from type ‘struct FILE *’ plik2=fopen(name, "a");

code fragment (I could post more but it should be irrelevant)

```
char name[50]; 
plik2=fopen(name, "a");
```

What I really want is to pass to `fopen()` file name contained in `char *output` which is in the appropriate structure but sadly even the easiest way doesn't work right now.

Comment: It seems that `plik2` is of type `FILE` instead of `FILE *`

Comment: Provide complete but minimal example.

Comment: How on earth did you manage to conclude that the declaration of plik2 was irrelevant?

Comment: Incidentally, the reference to `struct FILE` in the error message is a bit of a red herring. The type `FILE` apparently happens to be a typedef for something called `struct FILE` on your particular implementation. It could be defined differently in other implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the error, you must have written something like:

```
FILE plik2;
```

instead of the correct:

```
FILE *plik2;
```

Treat `FILE *` as an opaque type.  You always write `FILE *` (almost always; occasionally, you might use `FILE **`) and never write `FILE`.

Comment: Do you mean "Treat `FILE` as an opaque type"?

Comment: Either or both; don't poke inside what a `FILE *` points at; use `FILE *` everywhere; don't use `FILE` ever.  I think I mean 'use `FILE *` as the type' (omitting opaque from the discussion).  I'm not convinced my usage is wrong; your alternative would not be wrong.

Comment: @KeithThompson Probably treat *both* as opaque. Never dereference a `FILE*`, for instance...

Comment: @Roddy: Agreed. `FILE*` isn't *completely* opaque; we know it's a pointer. But code using it shouldn't treat it as one, and in particular shouldn't try to dereference it. (A conforming but perverse implementation *could*, I suppose, have `fopen()` return a POSIX-style integer descriptor cast to `FILE*`; portable code shouldn't break even under such an implementation.)

Comment: Wow, and I spent almost whole day reading about pointers, char arrays and such stuff.. still worth it tho. Thanks a lot!